# Packet Sending In Java

Tags: java, packet

Ok, I am trying to send packets to a local game server, but packets and connections confuse me a bit. This is my code:

```
public class Packet{
DataOutputStream os;
DataInputStream is;

public void test() throws IOException 
{
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 25565);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    os.writeByte(1);
    os.writeInt(23);
    writeString2("TEST", os);
    os.writeLong(0);
    os.writeShort(0);
    os.writeInt(0);
    os.writeByte(0);
    os.writeByte(0);
    os.writeByte(0);
    os.writeByte(0);        
    Menu.log1.addElement("Testing");
}
```

But when I start it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Packet.test(Packet.java:29)
    at Menu$2.actionPerformed(Menu.java:309)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6373)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6138)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4735)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)`
```

Could somebody help me out with his, I't's been bothering me for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually make the `os` and `is` references point to some objects before using them:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 25565);
is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a lot of frustration,

Answer (score 0):

You use `os`, but by the look of things you've never initialized it, so it's `null`:

```
DataOutputStream os;
```